# Retrieving value from a link failed in $ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to assign the product ID to the value of link and pass to $ajax so that the $ajax could use this variable and pass it to another php to update the cart information. But, unfortunately, I failed in doing so. If I Simple set the var value in $ajax, it works.
Below is the link to pass value to $ajax.

```
<a id ="'.$row["id"].'" value ="100" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myCall();">
```

And in the Ajax I use:

```
script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function myCall() {
//var value = 50;
var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: ({id: value}),
        //dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $(".bottomcorners").html(msg);          
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

It fails.

Does anyone can help me with it? And, by the way, I tried to use `.load()`. It works, but the problem is that it just show me the product that I add. It seems that it has no effect on server.  Anyway, my second question is will `$ajax` enable me to update the cart in my server? I am using an old version of WAMP(1.6.4)!

Comment: What is in your ajax.php?
Why do you think that nothing is working?
To see what happens on server with only client-side JS you can override `success` function in your `$.ajax` call

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the value of this in anchor:

```
<a id ="'.$row["id"].'" value ="100" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myCall(this);">
```

and at the time of call the function this should be like this:

```
function myCall(that) {
//var value = 50;
var value = $(that).attr('value');
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: ({id: value}),
        //dataType: "html"
    });
// and so on code
```

**EDIT**

if you want the id and value both then use following code:

```
var value = $(that).attr('value');
var id = $(that).attr('id');
```

and pass it in data as following:

```
data: ({id: id, value: value})
```

Comment: @user2295136 what you want to update value or value on the basis of id?

Comment: the ID i am passing to ajax.php is the actually id of the product. So I want to pass this id to ajax.php, and then, in the ajax.php, it will add the product to cart acording to its id.

Comment: @user2295136 ok, so where is your id, is that the value or id in anchor.

Comment: the id is got from database '.$row["id"].'. I don't know what the anchor is. sorry, I AM NEW TO aJAX

Comment: ok, so the in anchor tag you should echo the id as it is html.

Comment: I think we find the problem. Like this ? <a id ="<?php echo '.$row["id"].';?>"  But it seems no outcome? Even I echo before anchor. why it is so ? can you help me?

Comment: '.$row["id"].'
<a id ='.$row["id"].' This first line can be seen, but the second one, seems doesn't work?

Comment: but what about value attribute, I assign its value to "100" only for testing. Logically, the value attribute should be fine.

Comment: do you have firebug adones in your browser there you can see the output and can get the error there. in firebug, in net tab there is XHR subtab use that to get the error and the out.

Comment: I will have a look on that. Hopefully, It is only due to the browser. THANKS A LOT!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = $(this).attr('value');
```

You are retrieving the value (value="100") instead of the id, it should be:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

If you want to pass both:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {id: id, value: value }
    //dataType: "html"
});
```

You can also do it like this:

```
$.get("ajax.php", {id: id, value: value});
```

Regarding your second question:

AJAX will execute "ajax.php" ***IN THE SERVER***, so if you edit your cart in "ajax.php" it will work fine.

Comment: Hey, I also tried yours, but.. same stories. In fact, in the ajax.php, I do use a random() to echo some number for the sake of testing. I can get the random number. but the following bunch doesn't work.   $ID = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['value'];
echo $ID,$value;

Comment: Both of your methods work for echoing the random()function in the ajax.php, but failed to echo the id and value. Any other suggestion? or clue?

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you please post your "ajax.php"?

Comment: <?php
echo '<p>Hi I am some random ' . rand() .' output from the server.</p>';
$ID = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['value'];
echo $ID,$value;
?>

Comment: As you can see, for testing, the rand number can be displayed in my div. but neither id nor value can be displayed.

Comment: hmm could you try to 1st get the values and then display it all in a single echo?

Comment: try to open the url to ajax.php and add at the end of the url `?id=1&value=2`. This SHOULD work, if it doesn't there's something wrong with ajax.php

Comment: Like this ?   url: "ajax.php?id=1&value=2",

Comment: Then what the problem is ?how should I do?

Comment: then the problem is you are not capturing the values right in your javascript... try to set id=1 and value=2 just before making the ajax call, if that works it means you are not geting the correct values.